# Cross-product Exercise

Tags: analysis, exterior-algebra, cross-product

I am doing some problems in Spivak's calculus on manifolds, and I was stuck on this one. It says that:

If $w_1, ... ,w_{n-1} \in \mathbb{R}^n$, show that $$| w_1 \times ... \times w_{n-1}| = \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})}$$ where $g_{ij} = \langle w_i, w_j \rangle$.

There is a hint that asks for us to apply Problem 4-3 to a "certain" $n-1$ dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$, where problem 4-3 basically says that, given the volume element $\omega \in \Lambda^n(V)$ determined by $T$ and $\mu$ with $w_1, ... ,w_n \in V$, then $$| \omega(w_1, ... , w_{n})| = \sqrt{\det(g_{ij})}$$ where $g_{ij} = T(w_i, w_j)$.

The problem that I am having with this question is that it's not clear how the hint actually helps us. I was thinking, it seems we should be taking $T$ to be the usual inner product, but then in order to apply 4-3 we need to choose an orientation, and I'm not sure how we can do that.
Moreover, I'm not sure where the volume element is coming in, because it doesn't seem to be encountered in the actual problem itself. I'm also wondering what this $n-1$ dimensional subspace is supposed to be.

I was able to write out the norm of the cross product itself as a determinant (by definition), but I can't see any further reductions from there. Any advice on how to proceed?

Comment: Youn should have $\omega(v_1,\dots,v_n)$.

Comment: I'm sorry, but I'm not sure what you mean by this. Could you further elaborate (is there a typo that you've made?)

Comment: Oh, sorry, $w_1,\dots,w_n$. The use of $g_{ij}$ with both $n-1$ and $n$ vectors/indices is highly confusing. I’ll offer a hint that you want to take $w_n$ to be a unit vector orthogonal to $w_1,\dots,w_{n-1}$.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand. The question does not define a $w_n$, it's only $w_1, ... , w_{n-1}$. I would imagine the cross product is supposed to be that $w_n$ (which you can see in one of the answers below), however, I don't see how that leads to a solution. And I'm still confused about how the exercise 4-3 even comes into play here.

Comment: If $\omega\in \Lambda^n(V)$, then it needs to be evaluated on $n$ vectors.

Comment: Yes, thank you for pointing this out. I had written problem 4-3 incorrectly; I have edited it above. So if we choose $w_n$ to be related to the cross-product, we can use 4-3. I'm still not sure how to apply it though. I understand why the person's solution below *should* work, intuitively, but it's not clear why it actually follows from 4-3. We can choose $T = \langle , \rangle$ and then how do we know $\mu$? And further if we choose $\mu$, how can we then show that $\omega$ acting on the $n$ vectors in the cross-product?

Comment: It would help if you edited your post to include Spivak's actual definition of the cross-product. That is essential. And you should comment/explain that $\mu$ is itself a *choice* of orientation.